# Update Youtube iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

i am trying to dynamically update src attribute of an Youtube iframe using jQuery.
Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>


<ul>        
<li>Reading comprehension. <span>
 http://www.youtube.com/embed/O9AuuYOdCGc?rel=0</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

And JavaScript

```
    $('.manipulated li').click(function(e) {
    var source = $(this).children('span').html();
    $('iframe').attr('src',source);
});
```

The goal is that after I click on li item, the source of an iframe would be updated and the user will play different clip at the same iframe.

Any ideas, what is wrong here, or how this could be done?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById['iframeID'].src = newSource;`?

Answer (score 3):

In JQuery, when you use `.html();` it includes the tag. In this case, you are setting the source of the iframe to  `<span>http://www.youtube.com/embed/O9AuuYOdCGc?rel=0</span>`, not just the url. 
Instead use:

```
$('.manipulated li').click(function(e) {
    var source = $(this).children('span').text();
    $('iframe').attr('src',source);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the way to do it without any JavaScript
1. add id to iframe:
2. instead of span, add  tag to li, with href attribute equal to youtube link
3. target  tag to an iframe

```
<iframe name="testClip" id="testClip" width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <ul>
 <li>
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/O9AuuYOdCGc?rel=0" target="testClip">Reading comprehension.</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

In this case iframe updates automatically.